# whose mass would be more?

Tags: radioactivity

Let us consider a beta (-) particle is emitted from a radioactive source(beta decay). On the other hand, let an electron being emitted from a metal surface (photoelectric effect).
My book says that since beta particle gets out with high velocity from the nucleus, so its relativistic mass increases as compared to the electron emitted from metal surface(low velocity generally).
So my question is:
Why is the beta particle emitted with high velocity?

Answer (score 0):

The electron emitted during beta decay does not always have high speed.  Its kinetic energy (which is related to its speed) can have a spectrum of values (see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/beta.html). Briefly, in the rest frame of the initial proton, the electron energy depends on the energy which the anti neutrino, neutron and proton have after the decay.  [Beta decay is: $p\rightarrow n + \bar \nu +e^-$]

The energy of the electron emitted by photoelectric effect depends on how strongly it is bound to the material from which it is emitted and the energy of the photons (which depends on the frequency of the EM radiation) incident on the material.  $E_{electron}=E_{photon}-E_{binding}$.

Therefore you can't really generalise and say that electrons from beta decay move faster.